# How to filter defects / requirements by summary / name in HP-ALM with regexp-like syntax?

Tags: quality-center, hp-alm

What kind of syntax is it possible to use in HP-ALM string filtering?

For example something like this: `*accounts?*(error|enter)*`

[image: HP-ALM defects pane]

Comment: For searching by keywords and stringing them together when you only know a few of the keywords the format is like: *Test* And *Something Else*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there are only locigal conditions and wildcards.

Maybe if you have a description like `This is my test-ticket` you can search for it with something like `*test*`. This works like if you use the SQL-Statement `LIKE` with a front and a back `%`. So `test*` would not find the example as it does not start with `test`. Same with `*test` as there are characters behind it.

If you have whitespace in your search you have to put it into double quotes ( `"`) like this: `"*my test*"`

And then you can combine those terms with `and`, `or`, `(`, `)`, `NOT`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `=` (see list in the select filter condition dialog).

As far as I know there are not more regExs but I'm not sure. I didn't find anything in the documentation about it.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer from bish: You can also filter like this:
`*text1*text2*` - so you do not need to put the filter into double quotes.

Usually I filter on different fields like:

```
Assigned to - me
Status - "not closed and not tested and not rejected" (without quotes)
```

Further information:
After you have configured a filter you can save it as a favorite. Just click on "**Favorites**" and then on "**Add to Favorites**"

[image: QC Organize Favorites]

Either save them under *private* so only you can use it or save them under *public* so everyone with access can use it.

This allows you to easily switch between several filters and use the favorite and then adapt it to your current need.

Comment: Info: The numbers of *recently used filters / favorites* can only be set globally by a site admin not by individual users.